# How to show AVRO data from one field in two columns?

Tags: avro

Let's say I have an AVRO file that was written as a record with one column named `c1`. 
When I read this file with the schema it was written with I get all the data from `c1`.

Now, is it possible to read exactly that file with another schema, that has for example three columns? One column named `c0` with a default value of `null`, one column named `c1` that returns all the values as with the first schema. And one column named `c2` with an alias of `c1` that also returns all values of c1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably implementation dependent. If using JavaScript is an option, [`avsc`](https://github.com/mtth/avsc) will let you do what you want. For example, if you write an Avro file using your first schema...

```js
const writerSchema = {
  type: 'record',
  name: 'Foo',
  fields: [{name: 'c1', type: 'int'}]
};

const encoder = avro.createFileEncoder('data.avro', writerSchema);

// Write a little data.
encoder.write({c1: 123});
encoder.write({c1: 45});
encoder.end({c1: 6789});
```

...then you can read it with the second schema simply as...

```js
const readerSchema = {
  type: 'record',
  name: 'Foo',
  fields: [
    {name: 'c0', type: ['null', 'int'], 'default': null},
    {name: 'c1', type: 'int'},
    {name: 'c2', aliases: ['c1'], type: 'int'},
  ]
};

// Decode the file and print out its data.
avro.createFileDecoder('data.avro', {readerSchema})
  .on('data', (val) => { console.log(val); });
```

...and the output will have the form you expect:

```
Foo { c0: null, c1: 123, c2: 123 }
Foo { c0: null, c1: 45, c2: 45 }
Foo { c0: null, c1: 6789, c2: 6789 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. I am doing this in java, more exactly i want hadoop / hive to do this for me. So you have anything experience in this Direktion? Basically i want to create an Externalter Table Usingen the second Schema änderungen still be able to get the rows you showed

Comment: I implemented your example in java. I get all values for C1 null. I Had to add Null to the Type of C1 otherwise i get an error

Comment: Maybe the Java implementation doesn't support this yet; you can try filing a feature request on the official board: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AVRO.